# How to shuffle the answers in my array using a foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, shuffle

I am making a quiz application and currently have a table following this format:

```
| id |     question     | option1 | option2 | option3 | answer |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | What is my name? |  Dave   |   Bob   | Charles | Linda  |
```

I currently have this code, which outputs all of the information i have in my table correctly:

```
<?php
//Connection code included above
$query="SELECT * FROM MatQuiz";                        

$result = mysql_query($query, $connect);

?>

<?php                                
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {                                

       echo $row['id'] . '.  ';
       echo $row['question'] . '<br><br>';                           

?>

    <input type="radio" name="ID <?php $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php $row['option1']; ?>"><?php echo $row['option1'] ?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="ID <?php $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php $row['option2']; ?>"><?php echo $row['option2']; ?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="ID <?php $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php $row['option3']; ?>"><?php echo $row['option3']; ?><br>
    <input type="radio" name="ID <?php $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php $row['answer']; ?>"><?php echo $row['answer']; ?><br><br>

<?php

    }                            

?>
```

This code outputs all of my questions in my DB table in the correct order, with associated radio buttons and answers.

What I want to do is shuffle the organisation of:

```
$row['option1'];
$row['option2'];
$row['option3'];
$row['answer'];
```

I know I need to use a Foreach loop, and assign the $row array values to another array and use the shuffle() function.  Whenever I do this, I encounter an error and says invalid argument.

How do I go about shuffling the organisation of the answers so they do not display in the same order each time?

Comment: Why can't you directly use the `$row['option2']` before `$row['option1']` directly?

Comment: for each database row, create an array of $Options. Add each row option and the answer to the $Options array. Then use shuffle($Options): http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php. Then use a forloop to present the $Option values

Comment: Sunny, because then all of the options would appear in the same order but starting option 2 first

Comment: `I encounter an error and says invalid argument` Show the code of that and show the real error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each database row, create an array of $Options. Add each row option and the answer to the $Options array.

Then use shuffle($Options): [PHP Shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)

Then use a forloop to present the $Option values

```
<?php                                
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $Options = array($row['option1'], $row['option2'], $row['option3'], $row['answer']); 
        shuffle($Options);                        

        echo $row['id'] . '.  ';
        echo $row['question'] . '<br><br>';                           

        foreach($Options as $Option){?>
             <input type="radio" name="ID <?php echo $row['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $Option; ?>"><?php echo $Option; ?><br>
       <?php }
    }
?>
```

Comment: this shouldn't be down-voted, as it provides a correct solution to the question.

Comment: maybe because of the lack of explanation on what you have done.

Comment: Fair enough, thought that my previous comment to the question would suffice. I'll update the answer. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Justbaron, thank you very much for your help, still fairly new to php so getting my head round using loops correctly.  Your answer works perfectly thank you.